# Get null for empty collection in LINQ Group

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on LINQ query and part of objective to do SQL database call once to achieve result. I have number of questions which may have collection of answers.

I need to choose all the questions and collection of answer and if there no answer for specific question, I still need it.

for code gives me only question which have answer but not ones without answer

```
var t3 = (Context.Answers
    .Include(answer => answer.AnswerStatusType)
    .Where(answer => Context.Questions.Where(q => q.profileId == ProfileId)
    .Any(t => t.Id == answer.QuestionId)))
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.QuestionId,
        x => x,
        (key, g) => new
        {
            Question = key,
            Answers = g.ToList(),
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Start with `Context.Questions` then...

Comment: If you are using EF, shouldn't you have a navigation property from `Questions` to `Answers`? If not, shouldn't you use a join?

Comment: how to add join, considering I need also question list which don't have any answer

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like this:

```
var t3 =
(
    from q in Context.Questions
    where q.profileId == ProfileId
    join a in Context.Answers on q.Id equals a.QuestionId into gas
    select new
    {
        Question = q,
        Answers = gas.ToList(),
    }
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and solved it with this giant query, which could probably be optimized, but maybe it will help someone with a similar problem.

```
        // Perform left join to get all the questions (even those that don't have answers)
        var results = (from quiz in db.Quizzes
                      join question in db.Questions on quiz.QuestionID equals question.QuestionID
                      from answer in db.QuestionAnswers.Where(a => question.QuestionID == a.QuestionID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where quiz.QuizID == quizId
                      group (answer != null ? new AnswerVM()
                      {
                          AnswerId = answer.AnswerID,
                          AnswerText = answer.AnswerText,
                          Correct = question.CorrectAnswerID != null ? answer.AnswerID == question.CorrectAnswerID : false,
                      } : null) // For the questions with no answers 
                      by new
                      {
                          question.QuestionID,
                          question.DisplayOrder,
                          question.QuestionText,
                          question.CorrectAnswerID
                      } into g
                      select new QuestionVM
                      {
                          QuestionId = g.Key.QuestionID,
                          QuestionText = g.Key.QuestionText,
                          CorrectAnswerId = g.Key.CorrectAnswerID,
                          Answers = g.ToList()
                      })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => {
                    // If there are no answers then group by will return the list with one value (null), 
                    // then we need to change the answers list to be null (not the list with one null value)
                    if (x.Answers.Count(a => a != null) <= 0)
                    {
                        x.Answers = null;
                    }
                    return x;
                }).ToList();
```